# Summing up a column based on multiple Criterion

Tags: excel, vba

Basically

Column 1 contains many names,
Column 2 contains the Unique version of those many names,
Column 3 contains either 1 or 0

I want to sum the values in Column 3 based on Column 1 matching Column 2

EG

```
A        B        C
VBA     VBA       1
VBA     XY        0
XY      ZX        1
ZX                1
XY                1
VBA               0
XY                1
ZX                1
```

So I want it to produce a 4th column equal in length to Column B as follows

```
VBA    1
XY     3
ZX     2
```

I've tried a few different ways and I just cant seem to get it to work.
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: `=SUMIF(A:A,B2,C:C)` and fill down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$1:$C$8)*($A$1:$A$8=B1))
```

Drag/Copy down as required. Change range as needed. See image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Ah thank you for your help. This methods shorter than one I just figured out. I managed to get it to Count the cells If the range in column A matches the data in column B but only If the Range in Column D is greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking for another method aside from the above SUMIF method:

If its all on the Same sheet:

```
Cells(I, "C").Value = Application.CountIfs(Range("B:B"), Cells;
(I, "A").Value, Range("D:D"), "1")
```

If its on multiple sheets:

```
Sheets("SheetName").Cells(I, "C").Value = 
Application.CountIfs(Sheets("SheetName").Range("B:B"), Sheets("SheetName");
.Cells(I, "A").Value, Sheets("SheetName").Range("D:D"), "1")
```

There is probably a neater way of doing it. You could set a variable for the sheet names rather than typing Sheets("Sheetname") over and over.